# How to get current content view of activity?

Tags: android, onbackpressed, setcontentview

I have a content view say primary set on main activity, when clicked on a button, it sets another content view say secondary with setContentView(R.layout.sec_content). What i want now that when Back Button Pressed, It should set the primary content if current view is secondary otherwise it should close the activity. how do i do that?
here is my code

```
public class Ch_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button men1, men2, men3;
TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ch_1);

    men1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.men1);
    men1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_read__view);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.read_view);
            tv1.setText("This is text in READ_VIEW activity");




        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Yes i am using Android Studio.

Comment: Sorry, i am new  to android.

Comment: Rather than create two layouts why don't you create a second activity for your alternative layout, your button will open the second activity and your onBackPressed will behave naturally (take you back to previous activity (layout)?

Comment: yes, that i can do. but i have many buttons to add in my activity and set the text accordingly, so if i use activity, i have to create many activity. what i want to set text in the same layout for all my buttons. i only stuck when it comes to back button. is there any way to solve this. like setting an argument for onBackButtonPressed, if currentView == secondary {setContentView(R.layout.prim_content)} otherwise close activity.

Comment: Create 2 Activity instead of layout, if not try switching visibility of layout instead changing the ContentViews.

Comment: I think the best solution and easiest is to use two fragments, then simply use fragment transactions to switch between the two fragment layouts. Add the second fragment to the back stack and the back button will work to switch back to the previous fragment

Comment: Fragments are another option as mentioned, if your secondary layouts are all simply textViews why not use dialogs? Create an activity dialog and use a case switch to set the text accordingly? This is a tough one to help with given the very limited information around you project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Boolean isClose = true;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void onpressed(View view){
    isClose = false;
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isClose){
        finish();
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        isClose = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How can u set 2 Views, same time like `setContentView` twice, which has already a parent view.

Comment: there is boolean variable.. if it is true than you are finish your activity else it will remove the current view and add new view

Comment: Now when i press back button it takes me to previous layout rather than to close activity, that fine, but when it returns to previous layout no button works now?

Comment: try to use onclick method rather than setonclickListern like this i update the post see.

Comment: It does not work. Can you figure it out what should be the possible reason. It works fine on the first attempt but when i come back to the main activity by pressing back button it does not work.

Comment: Yes that worked. i was doing something wrong in declaring the onpressed function. Thanks alot.